# Sum of the components of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Introduction to Linear Algebra (Strang 5th ed) problem 6 page 8.

**What does it mean when components of a vector add to zero?**
The solution from the instructor's manual doesn't give additional clues, and maybe it doesn't mean more than that?
Does someone have an insight on the sum of components of vectors?

---

#### The problem set:

### [image]

#### The instructor's manual answer:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it means is that you've discovered an *invariant* property of linear combinations of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, which can then be used to identify whether a vector belongs to that set of combinations.

If you're familiar with the dot product of vectors, then "the components sum to zero" can be interpreted slightly differently - note that $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{r} = v_x r_x + v_y r_y + v_z r_z = 0$ is satisfied if $r_x = r_y = r_z = 1$, i.e. $\mathbf{r} = (1, 1, 1)$. And if the dot product of two non-zero vectors is zero, then that means that the vectors must be *perpendicular* to each other.

So the vector $(1,1,1)$ is in fact perpendicular to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, and as a result it is perpendicular to all vectors of the form $a\mathbf{v} + b\mathbf{w}$, in other words it is perpendicular to the plane formed from all possible linear combinations of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$. More generally, for *any* two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, if the vector $\mathbf{r}$ is perpendicular to both of them then it is perpendicular to all linear combinations of them. This falls out pretty nicely from just noting that $(a \mathbf{v} + b \mathbf{w}) \cdot \mathbf{r} = a \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{r} + b \mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{r} = a \times 0 + b \times 0 = 0$

You can even find $\mathbf{r}$ in 3D space pretty quickly, if you're familiar with the cross product, since the cross product of two vectors is always perpendicular to both of them. As it turns out, in this example $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w} = (1, 1, 1)$ which brings us full circle.

Comment: Phrased slightly differently, the vectors all lie in the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. As we will find later, this is a subspace and hence is closed under linear combinations.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! `an invariant property of linear combinations of  and ` yes indeed. Does this generalize, or is it specific to these two vectors, and their combinations? i/e (1) do all vectors whose components add to zero lie on that same plane (this seems to be what @TedShifrin is saying)? (2) do all vectors whose components add to an arbitrary number (in R) lie in their own same plane? How do we use that property?
(I'll ask another question if this is too much for a comment, pls let me know)

Comment: Note that the equation I wrote is precisely summing the three components of the vector and setting it equal to zero! ConMan's explanation ties in because the vector $(1,1,1)$ is the *normal vector* to that plane. However, if you make the sum a nonzero number, this will no longer pass through the origin and will *not* be closed under linear combinations.

Comment: @ConMan: Perhaps intermingling the cross product with the times for multiplication of real numbers is more confusion than it's worth.  (I realize that dot product is also spoken for. Maybe just parentheses for multiplication?)

Comment: Got it @TedShifrin , thank you! This opens more questions, but I can move on.

Comment: The main clarification I should probably add is that the dot product of two 3D vectors is the sum of the pairwise product of their components - so $(a_x, a_y, a_z) \cdot (b_x, b_y, b_z) = a_x b_x + a_y b_y + a_z b_z$. So in general the property you're looking for isn't that the components sum to some value, but instead that a specific linear cominbation of the components sums to zero, i.e. that $a v_x + b v_y + c v_z = a w_x + b w_y + c w_z = 0$, where $(a, b, c)$ is the vector perpendicular to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$.

Answer (score 1):

So,
$$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{w} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Essentially,
$v_{x}+v_{y}+v_{z} = 0$ and $w_{x}+w_{y}+w_{z} = 0$
Therefore, all elementary row operations will still scale the values and maintain the principle that
$$\lambda\sum v_{t}=0$$
where $v$ is a given vector, and $\lambda$ is a scaling factor.
$$\vec{\alpha}=
\begin{bmatrix}
cv_{x}+dw_{x}\\
cv_{y}+dw_{y}\\
cv_{z}+dw_{z}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Applying the above postulation:
$$\sum v_{t}=0$$
where $v$ is a given vector,
$$\vec{\alpha}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
3\\
-6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is valid because the sum of components is 0, however,
$$\vec{\alpha}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
3\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Does not satisfy the postulation because the sum of the components is not $0$

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you have nicely reformulated my answer to the problem and the answer from the instructor manual.